# Word problem doubt

Tags: word-problem

A baker used $0.6$ ton of whole wheat flour each month. $1/9$ of the whole wheat flour is used for muffins.if the baker adds $0.1$ ton of all purpose flour to the muffin mix,how much does the muffin mix weigh?

I know the answer is : $0.6 \times 1/9 + 0.1$ ,but I have a doubt ,could you explain more why the answer  is $0.6 \times 1/9$ ? I got the impression it’s $0.6 - 1/9$

Comment: A fraction of always means multiplication. Think about what one half of $0.6$ tons means. Half of  $0.6$ is $0.3$ or $\frac{1}{2}\times 0.6$. It works that way for all fractions.

Answer (score 1):

The baker uses a total of $0.6$ tons of whole wheat flour each month.  Out of that total, $1/9$ of the total goes into muffins.  That means that $1/9$ of the $0.6$ tons is used for muffins.  That quantity is $0.6 \times 1/9$.  We need to add to that the extra 0.1 tons that the baker adds on top of what they've already used to get a total of $0.6 \times 1/9 + 0.1$ tons of flour.

Comment: That quantity is 0.6×1/9
I can’t understand why you have to multiply

Comment: Because that's what multiplication means - when we write $0.6 \times 1/9$ we can interpret this as one ninth of $0.6$ tons.